# Unable to ping docker container

Tags: docker

New to docker on mac osx. I am building a ubuntu image from the base phusion image to use as a git server. Using the following file to install the base and needed software. This works great. However, I am unable to ping the machine.

**EDIT**

---

I am unable to ping the machine. I can run the image and see the container in the ps command. I can also exec bash into it.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND               CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
54e4cef78445        git-ssh_img         "/usr/sbin/sshd -D"   44 minutes ago      Up 44 minutes       22/tcp              git-ssh
```

The following also works

```
docker exec -it 54e4cef78445 ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (173.194.219.147) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ya-in-f147.1e100.net (173.194.219.147): icmp_seq=1 ttl=61 time=65.1 ms
64 bytes from ya-in-f147.1e100.net (173.194.219.147): icmp_seq=2 ttl=61 time=67.1 ms
```

---

Dockerfile:

```
# Use phusion/baseimage as base image. To make your builds reproducible, make
# sure you lock down to a specific version, not to `latest`!
# See https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker/blob/master/Changelog.md for
# a list of version numbers.
FROM phusion/baseimage:0.9.18

# Use baseimage-docker's init system.
CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]

# ...put your own build instructions here...

ENV TERM xterm

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install openssh-server
RUN apt-get -y install git \
    libxml2-dev \
    python \
    build-essential \
    make \
    gcc \
    python-dev \
    python-pip

# Clean up APT when done.
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Setting openssh
# RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN sed -i "s/#PasswordAuthentication yes/PasswordAuthentication no/" /etc/ssh/sshd_config

# Adding git user
RUN adduser --system git
RUN mkdir -p /home/git/.ssh

# Clearing and setting authorized ssh keys
RUN echo '' > /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys
RUN echo 'First key' >> /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys
# RUN echo 'Second SSH public key' >> /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys
# ...

# Updating shell to bash
RUN sed -i s#/home/git:/bin/false#/home/git:/bin/bash# /etc/passwd

EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

Inspect command:

```
[
{
    "Id": "54e4cef78445e1308b744297edc1d3d153932ce7724e87b35dc3690f8ffe41a2",
    "Created": "2015-12-10T21:01:16.683875853Z",
    "Path": "/usr/sbin/sshd",
    "Args": [
        "-D"
    ],
    "State": {
        "Running": true,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 13930,
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2015-12-10T21:01:16.763739339Z",
        "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "Image": "b2c6f9604ceca1e112dc0560aa4d0c50596d27c80256c544613f1d6badf6ccda",
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "EndpointID": "87f12f9b527f3e0d7f823f1e2c88b0d0e860ff2d1687568d0a15cfa9fdfe22c3",
        "Gateway": "172.17.42.1",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.26",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:1a",
        "NetworkID": "a60ea78a8239baed013f9bfb1b2719a599ddef7745170e3c17eeab743a391ebe",
        "PortMapping": null,
        "Ports": {
            "22/tcp": null
        },
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/54e4cef78445",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null
    },
    "ResolvConfPath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/54e4cef78445e1308b744297edc1d3d153932ce7724e87b35dc3690f8ffe41a2/resolv.conf",
    "HostnamePath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/54e4cef78445e1308b744297edc1d3d153932ce7724e87b35dc3690f8ffe41a2/hostname",
    "HostsPath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/54e4cef78445e1308b744297edc1d3d153932ce7724e87b35dc3690f8ffe41a2/hosts",
    "LogPath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/54e4cef78445e1308b744297edc1d3d153932ce7724e87b35dc3690f8ffe41a2/54e4cef78445e1308b744297edc1d3d153932ce7724e87b35dc3690f8ffe41a2-json.log",
    "Name": "/git-ssh",
    "RestartCount": 0,
    "Driver": "aufs",
    "ExecDriver": "native-0.2",
    "MountLabel": "",
    "ProcessLabel": "",
    "AppArmorProfile": "",
    "ExecIDs": null,
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": null,
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "LxcConf": [],
        "Memory": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 0,
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "CpuPeriod": 0,
        "CpusetCpus": "",
        "CpusetMems": "",
        "CpuQuota": 0,
        "BlkioWeight": 0,
        "OomKillDisable": false,
        "MemorySwappiness": -1,
        "Privileged": false,
        "PortBindings": {},
        "Links": null,
        "PublishAllPorts": false,
        "Dns": null,
        "DnsSearch": null,
        "ExtraHosts": null,
        "VolumesFrom": null,
        "Devices": [],
        "NetworkMode": "default",
        "IpcMode": "",
        "PidMode": "",
        "UTSMode": "",
        "CapAdd": null,
        "CapDrop": null,
        "GroupAdd": null,
        "RestartPolicy": {
            "Name": "no",
            "MaximumRetryCount": 0
        },
        "SecurityOpt": null,
        "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
        "Ulimits": null,
        "LogConfig": {
            "Type": "json-file",
            "Config": {}
        },
        "CgroupParent": "",
        "ConsoleSize": [
            0,
            0
        ]
    },
    "GraphDriver": {
        "Name": "aufs",
        "Data": null
    },
    "Mounts": [],
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "54e4cef78445",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": true,
        "AttachStderr": true,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "22/tcp": {}
        },
        "Tty": false,
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": [
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "TERM=xterm"
        ],
        "Cmd": [
            "/usr/sbin/sshd",
            "-D"
        ],
        "Image": "git-ssh_img",
        "Volumes": null,
        "WorkingDir": "",
        "Entrypoint": null,
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {}
    }
}
]
```

Comment: I am unclear on the question. What are you trying to ping, the container or the host the container is running on? The former is only possible on the same host running the container.

Comment: @AndyShinn trying to ssh into the container from host. So the idea is to add container as a git remote origin and use as git server. I was going to put it up on bluemix/amazon cloud as docker image. Currently, when I "git remote add" from host, it times out. Maybe not thinking about docker correctly here :(.

Comment: That is fair enough. But there are some important things missing from your question. What was the Docker command used to start the git SSH daemon container? What is the Docker host IP address? What command did you use to add the git remote?

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in "[Can't visit `http://172.17.0.2:5000` after starting docker registry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34219168/6309)", you cannot use the internal IP made for [container-to-container communication](https://coreos.com/flannel/docs/latest/flannel-config.html).

You need to use the IP returned by `$(docker-machine ip <yourMachine>)` to actually ping the machine which runs your container.

---

Update February 2017, docker 1.13+: as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34212236/unable-to-ping-docker-container/34219568?noredirect=1#comment72041193_34219568) by [kboom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1130975/kboom), you now have [Docker for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/docker-toolbox/) which uses a lightweight hypervisor ([HyperKit](https://github.com/docker/HyperKit/)), which allows to be bound to `localhost` (but still you cannot visit internal addresses).

Comment: Just to note - things changed a little bit since"Docker for Mac" or "Docker for Windows" have been introduced. Now it's bound to localhost itself (but still you cannot visit internal addresses)

Comment: @kboom Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.