# Can't visit `http://172.17.0.2:5000` after starting docker registry

Tags: docker, registry

On a mac system, I start the register following the [deploy document](https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/docs/deploying.md):

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
```

And its ip is `"IPAddress": "172.17.0.2"`, which is from the command `docker inspect <cid>`

But I can't telnet its port:

```
$ telnet 172.17.0.2 5000
Trying 172.17.0.2...
telnet: connect to address 172.17.0.2: Can't assign requested address
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Or

```
$ curl http://172.17.0.2:5000
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
```

I ssh to the container to check it:

```
$ docker exec -it cda bash
root@cda4c64efd06:/# netstat -an
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp6       0      0 :::5000                 :::*                    LISTEN
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
root@cda4c64efd06:/# curl -I http://localhost:5000
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Date: Fri, 11 Dec 2015 07:34:17 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

root@cda4c64efd06:/#
```

Seems like it's binding `tcp6` not normally `tcp`.

Where is wrong?

Comment: Those instructions are for Linux, not OSX. Are you using docker-machine or boot2docker?

Comment: Yes, the `docker` command is running with a `docker machine`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using docker-machine, see "[Port forwarding in docker-machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32175164/6309)"

- either port forward the 5000 port on the VirtualBox level (meaning `localhost:5000` will work)

  ```
  VBoxManage controlvm "boot2docker-vm" natpf1 "tcp-port5000,tcp,,5000,,5000";
  ```
- or use the ip returned by `$(docker-machine ip <yourMachine>)`

Comment: You are right, I should use the ip of the machine! Which is not the ip of the container `172.17.0.2`, but the one which shows when starting "Docker Quickstart Terminal", for now, it's `192.168.99.100`

Comment: @Freewind Yes, 172.17.0.2 should be the flannel network created by docker created for container to container communication (https://coreos.com/flannel/docs/latest/flannel-config.html)